# Binding a 2 dimensional bool array to datagrid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have to create a Matrix like datagrid of type bool using 2D Array. I have a set of boolean string that is needed to be evaluated for each cell in the datagrid as follows

for e.g

cell[0,0] = ((server1 || server 2) && server 3)

cell[0,1] = ((server1 && server 3) && server 4)

cell[1,0] = ((server3 && server 2) || server 4)

the values for server N is Running or Stopped and it is got from the database.

how to create a 2D matrix datagrid and how to evaluate the boolean string so that the final result is TRUE or FALSE for each datagrid cell.

I had a look at this link [2D array for string](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/b2731356-180d-4265-8103-fd219565e8ba) and took this as an example, but I dont know where should I call these evaluation strings. Do I have to store them in an XML file and then call them or is there anyother way to call them..

What I have tried :

```
public MatrixPage()
{
InitializeComponent();
bool[,] matrixcell = new bool[10, 22];

matrixcell[0, 0] = // should I place the Evaluation string here;
matrixcell[0, 1] = ;
for  (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
for (int j = 0; j < 22; j++)
{
 matrixcell[i, j] = // or Should I call here the evaluation boolean string for each    iteration respective to the row/column from a file like XML or a any other file ??
}
}
 var datsource = (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, matrixcell.GetLength(0))
    select new clsdatasource(matrixcell[i, 0], matrixcell[i, 1], matrixcell[i,3])).ToList();
 this.dg1.ItemsSource = datsource;
}
public class clsdatasource
{
public bool str1 { get; set; }
public bool str2 { get; set; }
public bool str3 { get; set; }
public clsdatasource(bool s1, bool s2,bool s3)
{
 this.str1 = s1;
 this.str2 = s2;
 this.str3 = s3;
}
}
```

XAML

```
  <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dg1" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="System1" Binding="{Binding str1}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="System2" Binding="{Binding str2}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="System3" Binding="{Binding str3}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

Kindly help.. if the question is not clear to understand, please comment, I will try to explain more clearly

Comment: Is the grid meant to be static?  If not it should inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged.  The bools will evaluate to their string representation during the presentation.  The language itself does not allow an implicit conversion from bool to string, but binding will handle it automatically.  Which aspect is not working?

Comment: @GarryVass No I want the grid to be dynamically created. evaluating the boolean string is not a problem here, I dont know where to place these boolean string for each [cell] ( i mean in which file format should I place them so that I can retieve them during the iteration). and after retriveing them how to place them in theor respective matrix cell

Comment: OK, that's a bit clearer, thanks.  If you needed persistent storage, then your hunch about XML would be the way I would go.  You'll need a parameterless constructor for clsdatasource class, and I would deserialize the data into an ObservableCollection<clsdatasource>.  But that's based solely upon what I understand your question to be now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, if possible can u please post an simple example how it works. that would be really a kick start for my progress now

Comment: I can put some pseudo code that Serializes and Deserializes your data if that's of any use.  I don't know the part about the servers being up and what-not...

Comment: ok sure.. that will do .. thanks indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class would like like this...

```
public class Clsdatasource
{
    public bool Str1 { get; set; }
    public bool Str2 { get; set; }
    public bool Str3 { get; set; }
    public Clsdatasource(){}
    public Clsdatasource(bool s1, bool s2, bool s3)
    {
        Str1 = s1;
        Str2 = s2;
        Str3 = s3;
    }
}
```

And your collection of those would look like this...

```
public class ClsdataSourceCollection : ObservableCollection<Clsdatasource>
{
    private const string FileName = "MyData.xml";
    private readonly XmlSerializer _serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Clsdatasource>));
    public void LoadData(Action onCompleted)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileName))
        {
            var s = _serializer.Deserialize(sr) as List<Clsdatasource>;
            if (s != null)
            {
                Clear();
                s.ForEach(Add);
            }
        }
        onCompleted();
    }
    public void SaveData(Action onCompleted)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(FileName))
        {
            List<Clsdatasource> tosave = new List<Clsdatasource>();
            tosave.AddRange(this);
            _serializer.Serialize(sw, tosave);
        }
        onCompleted();
    }
}
```

And you could see what's going on with this snippet...

```
private static void TestSaving()
{
    ClsdataSourceCollection collection = new ClsdataSourceCollection();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        collection.Add(new Clsdatasource(true, true, true));
    }
    collection.SaveData(()=> Console.WriteLine("Saved"));
}
private static void TestLoading()
{
    ClsdataSourceCollection collection = new ClsdataSourceCollection();
    collection.LoadData(() => Console.WriteLine("Loaded"));
}
```

Those two methods just do a create, save, and load.  The artefact is an XML file in the root app directory called MyData.xml.  You need to code in all the corner cases and error detection and races.

The last step in the whole shebang is to set this.dg1.ItemsSource = collection;

Remember that if you want real-time updates to your grid, the Clsdatasource class has to inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged, which is a different question altogether.

That should get you started with serialization.  It comes 'out of the box' since about .NET 3 or so....